# Detect GoPro camera model from MP4

Tags: action-cam

I have raw video file named GP010661.MP4, which seems to be taken with GoPro. Is there a way to detect the exact GoPro camera model and mode used for this video?

This is the the output of ExifTool:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.46
File Name                       : GP010661.MP4
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 3753 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2014:11:27 09:37:20+03:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2015:02:19 09:22:46+03:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2015:02:19 09:22:46+03:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : MP4
MIME Type                       : video/mp4
Major Brand                     : MP4 Base w/ AVC ext [ISO 14496-12:2005]
Minor Version                   : 0.0.0
Compatible Brands               : avc1, isom
Movie Header Version            : 0
Create Date                     : 2014:11:27 11:19:55
Modify Date                     : 2014:11:27 11:19:55
Time Scale                      : 90000
Duration                        : 0:17:25
Preferred Rate                  : 1
Preferred Volume                : 100.00%
Preview Time                    : 0 s
Preview Duration                : 0 s
Poster Time                     : 0 s
Selection Time                  : 0 s
Selection Duration              : 0 s
Current Time                    : 0 s
Next Track ID                   : 3
Track Header Version            : 0
Track Create Date               : 2014:11:27 11:19:55
Track Modify Date               : 2014:11:27 11:19:55
Track ID                        : 1
Track Duration                  : 0:17:25
Track Layer                     : 0
Track Volume                    : 0.00%
Image Width                     : 1920
Image Height                    : 1080
Graphics Mode                   : srcCopy
Op Color                        : 0 0 0
Compressor ID                   : avc1
Source Image Width              : 1920
Source Image Height             : 1080
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Compressor Name                 : .GoPro AVC encoder
Bit Depth                       : 24
Color Representation            : nclc 1 1 1
Gamma                           : 2.2
Video Frame Rate                : 59.94
Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
Media Header Version            : 0
Media Create Date               : 2014:11:27 11:19:55
Media Modify Date               : 2014:11:27 11:19:55
Media Time Scale                : 48000
Media Duration                  : 0:17:25
Handler Type                    : Audio Track
Handler Description             : .GoPro AAC
Balance                         : 0
Audio Format                    : mp4a
Audio Channels                  : 2
Audio Bits Per Sample           : 16
Audio Sample Rate               : 48000
Movie Data Size                 : 3933436091
Movie Data Offset               : 1474560
Avg Bitrate                     : 30.1 Mbps
Image Size                      : 1920x1080
Rotation                        : 0
```

The reason I need it, is that file chokes on my Ubuntu 14.04 with VLC and I couldn't even watch it. It took few days to recode the videos, and I do not want to run into the same problem again. If I know the camcoder model and mode, I can to ask people to use different camera or settings.

Comment: What are the specs of your computer?

Comment: @kazanaki, Intel® Pentium(R) D CPU 3.20GHz × 2, 8 Gb

Comment: Well your system is powerful enough. If you play the video with mplayer or xine does it still choke?

Comment: @kazanaki, `mplayer` doesn't choke, but it plays the video like 2x slower (audio is too quiet, but speed ok). Actually, `mplayer` warns after some time `Your system is too SLOW to play this!`

Comment: @kazanaki, wow `xine` did it. Sound is ok, picture is smooth and fast.

Comment: Ok. I added it as an official answer. Mplayer has a lot of backends (even an openGL one) so you might want to experiment. If xine works fine and you are happy then of course use that to view the videos..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MP4 files don't have as much data as .JPEG or .CR2 files so there is probally no way to know. Your cpu is that fast and GoPro footage is hard for the computer to play.

Answer (score 2):

This video is 1080p at 60 fps and 30Mb/s.

That rules-out quite a lot of cameras in the GoPro range. From the [current generation](http://shop.gopro.com/EMEA/compare?category=cameras), only the **GoPro Hero4 Silver** and **GoPro Hero4 Black** are capable of grater than 25Mb/s. [In the previous generation](https://gopro.com/support/articles/hero3plus-camera-comparison), only the top-end **GoPro Hero3+ Black** was capable of more than 25Mb/s.

Your video was almost certainly captured on one of these three cameras.

Comment: Yea, it suxx that guys could not choose file format that allows to store diagnostic information along with video data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your VLC installation has a problem.

If you try with an alternative player it might work! (like mplayer or xine)

Your system is powerful enough to handle GoPro videos.
Perhaps try installing the windows codecs in mplayer and also make sure that X-Windows has the xvideo extension enabled (any any other video related extensions)

Comment: Well, installing `xine` fixes the problem with slow playback, but it is still doesn't explain how to

Comment: Maybe xine is compiled with different flags than vlc. Especially the backend options for actually rendering the video.

Answer (score 1):

None of the data provided seems to be useful in identifying the camera model.  The best bet would probably be to ask the people who shot the footage about it.  They may remember which camera they used for the shoot.

Comment: I still have the file produced by the camera. Maybe that information just not in EXIF tag?

Comment: It is possible that exiftool couldn't read the particular tag maybe, but probably unlikely.  I believe EXIFtool is usually pretty complete.  Sometimes it outputs a code that may not be human readable, but I don't see any such values.

Answer (score 1):

The filename suggests that it's not a HERO6 Black, & HERO7 (White, Silver, Black) GH01xxxx.mp4 or GX01xxxx.mp4, but an older HERO with the filename pattern GOPRxxxx.mp4.

Camera Models: HD HERO2, HERO3, HERO3+, HERO (2014), HERO Session, HERO4, HERO5 Black, HERO5 Session, HERO (2018)
Single Video GOPRxxxx.mp4
Example GOPR1234.mp4

Camera Model: HERO6 Black, & HERO7 (White, Silver, Black)
Single Video GH01xxxx.mp4 or GX01xxxx.mp4
Example GH011234.mp4 or GX011234.mp4

See at gopro website for more details https://gopro.com/help/articles/question_answer/GoPro-Camera-File-Naming-Convention

Comment: Welcome! "See this link" answers are discouraged here in case they become unavailable in the future. Please try to summarize or paraphrase the contents of the link in your answer so that future readers can benefit from it.